# Dotnet run command giving me "error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment." error

Tags: c#, .net, ubuntu, runtime-error, monogame

So I downloaded MonoGame onto VScode using ubuntu. I'm trying to test it out and run the file to see if it works. When I type dotnet run into the terminal I get an error message:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.NoSuitableGraphicsDeviceException: Failed to create graphics device!
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MonoGame.OpenGL.GL.LoadExtensions()
   at MonoGame.OpenGL.GraphicsContext..ctor(IWindowInfo info)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.PlatformSetup()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice.Setup()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice..ctor(GraphicsAdapter adapter, GraphicsProfile graphicsProfile, Boolean preferHalfPixelOffset, PresentationParameters presentationParameters)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice(GraphicsDeviceInformation gdi)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GraphicsDeviceManager.CreateDevice()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoInitialize()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run(GameRunBehavior runBehavior)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in /home/joeyg/Development/code/6th_Mod/games/testMonoGame/testGame/Program.cs:line 3
```

I haven't made any changes to the code, I just made a new file and tried to see if it would display a blank canvas and it doesn't work. Can anyone help please?

Comment: MonoGame uses, as the name says, the mono framework. That contradicts with the (newer) dotnet runtime. Xna isn't compatible with dotnet at all, IIRC.